# How can I create a 3D platform game in Processing, including player movement, lava, and moving block obstacles?

Tags: 3d, processing, platform

It's very important please help. I want to add the following features to this code: The player I created can stay on top of the stages I created and cannot pass through it. If the player touches the lava, the game will stop and write "You Lost". If the player comes to the end platform that I created while pressing the lava, "You Win!!" write it. Let the stages I created move up and down on the y-axis.

```
< PImage imgLava,imgGrass, imgStone, imgP1;
//Player p;
float playerX = 0;
float playerY = 0;
float playerZ = 0;


float jumpHeight = 0;
float jumpSpeed = 0;
boolean isJumping = false;
boolean gameLost = false;
boolean gameWon = false;

void setup()
{
  fullScreen(P3D);

  camZ = (height/2) / tan((PI*60.0)/360.0);
  
  noStroke();
 textureMode(NORMAL);
  
  
   
  imgLava = loadImage("lava.jpeg");
  imgGrass = loadImage("grass.jpg");
 imgStone= loadImage("stone.png");
 imgP1= loadImage("p1.png");
//  p = new Player();
}
float camZ = 0;
 
void draw()
{
  background(0);
  /*camera(width/2, height/2, camZ, //camx, camy, camz
  width/2, height/2, 0, //lookx, looky, lookz
  0, 1, 0 //eyex, eyey, eyez
  );*/
  camera(0, 0, camZ, 
  0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1, 0);
  lights();
  rotateX(rotX + distY);
  rotateY(rotY + distX);
  
  scale(20);
  
 // p.update();
 // p.display();
  drawLava();
 drawPlatform();
 drawStage();
 drawEndPlatform();
drawPlayer();

   if (keyPressed) {
    if (keyCode == UP)
      camZ -= 5;
    if (keyCode == DOWN)
      camZ += 5;
    if (key == 'a' || key == 'A')
      playerX -= 0.1;
    if (key == 'd' || key == 'D')
      playerX += 0.1;
    if (key == 'w' || key == 'W')
      playerZ -= 0.1;
    if (key == 's' || key == 'S')
      playerZ += 0.1;
    if (key == ' ')
      jump();
  }
  if (isJumping) {
    performJump();
  }
  
}

void drawLava()
{
  int w = 1;
  int h = 1;
  beginShape(QUAD);
  texture(imgLava);
  
  vertex(-5, 1.0000, -54, 0, 0);
  vertex(5, 1.0000, -54, w, 0);
  vertex(5, 1.0000, 0, w, h);
  vertex(-5, 1.0000, 0, 0, h);
  endShape();
    if (playerY <= -height / 2 && playerZ <= 0 && playerZ >= -200) {
    gameLost = true;
  }

}

void drawPlatform()
{
int w = 1;
  int h = 1;
  beginShape(QUAD);
   texture(imgGrass);
  
  vertex(-2, 0.999, 0, 0, 0);
  vertex(2, 0.999, 0, w, 0);
  vertex(2, 0.999, -5, w, h);
  vertex(-2, 0.999, -5, 0, h);
  endShape();

}
int w=1,h=1;
 void drawStage()
 {

    beginShape(QUADS);
  texture(imgStone);
  
  //+Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -10, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -10, w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -10, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -10, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //-Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -15, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -15, w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -15, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -15, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //+X face
  vertex(1, -1, -10, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -15, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -15, w, h);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -10, 0, h);
  
  //-X face
  vertex(-1, -1, -10, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(-1, -1, -15, w, 0);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -15, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -10, 0, h);
  
  //-Y face
  vertex(-1, -1, -10, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -10, w, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -15, w, h);
  vertex(-1, -1, -15, 0, h);
  
  //+Y face
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -10, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -10, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -15, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -15, 0, h);
  endShape();
  
   beginShape(QUADS);
  texture(imgStone);
  
  //+Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -20, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -20 ,w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -20, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -20, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //-Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -25, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -25, w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -25, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -25, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //+X face
  vertex(1, -1, -20, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -25, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -25, w, h);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -20, 0, h);
  
  //-X face
  vertex(-1, -1, -20, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(-1, -1, -25, w, 0);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -25, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -20, 0, h);
  
  //-Y face
  vertex(-1, -1, -20, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -20, w, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -25, w, h);
  vertex(-1, -1, -25, 0, h);
  
  //+Y face
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -20, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -20, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -25, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -25, 0, h);
  endShape();
  
     beginShape(QUADS);
  texture(imgStone);
  
  //+Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -30, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -30 ,w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -30, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -30, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //-Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -35, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -35, w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -35, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -35, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //+X face
  vertex(1, -1, -30, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -35, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -35, w, h);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -30, 0, h);
  
  //-X face
  vertex(-1, -1, -30, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(-1, -1, -35, w, 0);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -35, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -30, 0, h);
  
  //-Y face
  vertex(-1, -1, -30, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -30, w, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -35, w, h);
  vertex(-1, -1, -35, 0, h);
  
  //+Y face
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -30, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -30, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -35, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -35, 0, h);
  endShape();
  
  
       beginShape(QUADS);
  texture(imgStone);
  
  //+Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -40, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -40 ,w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -40, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -40, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //-Z face
  vertex(-1, -1, -45, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -45, w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(1, 0.998, -45, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -45, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //+X face
  vertex(1, -1, -40, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(1, -1, -45, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -45, w, h);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -40, 0, h);
  
  //-X face
  vertex(-1, -1, -40, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(-1, -1, -45, w, 0);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -45, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -40, 0, h);
  
  //-Y face
  vertex(-1, -1, -40, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -40, w, 0);
  vertex(1, -1, -45, w, h);
  vertex(-1, -1, -45, 0, h);
  
  //+Y face
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -40, 0, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -40, w, 0);
  vertex(1, 0.998, -45, w, h);
  vertex(-1, 0.998, -45, 0, h);
  endShape();
 }
void drawEndPlatform()
{
int w = 1;
  int h = 1;
  beginShape(QUAD);
   texture(imgGrass);
  
  vertex(-2, 0.999, -49, 0, 0);
  vertex(2, 0.999, -49, w, 0);
  vertex(2, 0.999, -54, w, h);
  vertex(-2, 0.999, -54, 0, h);
  endShape();
   if (playerY <= -height / 2 && playerZ <= -50 && playerZ >= -55) {
    gameWon = true;
  }
}


void drawPlayer() {
  translate(playerX, playerY + jumpHeight, playerZ);
  //if (isJumping) {
  //  jumpHeight += jumpSpeed;
  //  jumpSpeed -= 0.01;
    
 //   if (jumpHeight <= 0) {
 //     isJumping = false;
 //     jumpHeight = 0;
   //   jumpSpeed = 0.2;
  //  }
 // }
 
 texture(imgP1);
 //+Z face
  vertex(-0.25, 0.75, -1, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(0.25, 0.75, -1, w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(0.25, 0.998, -1, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-0.25, 0.998, -1, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //-Z face
  vertex(-0.25, 0.75, -1.5, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(0.25, 0.75, -1.5, w, 0); //upper right corner
  vertex(0.25, 0.998, -1.5, w, h); //bottom right corner
  vertex(-0.25, 0.998, -1.5, 0, h); //bottom left corner
  
  //+X face
  vertex(0.25, 0.75, -1.0, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(0.25, 0.75, -1.5, w, 0);
  vertex(0.25, 0.998, -1.5, w, h);
  vertex(0.25, 0.998, -1.0, 0, h);
  
  //-X face
  vertex(-0.25, 0.75, -1.0, 0, 0); //upper left corner
  vertex(-0.25, 0.75, -1.5, w, 0);
  vertex(-0.25, 0.998, -1.5, w, h);
  vertex(-0.25, 0.998, -1.0, 0, h);
  
  //-Y face
  vertex(-0.25, 0.75, -1.0, 0, 0);
  vertex(0.25, 0.75, -1.0, w, 0);
  vertex(0.25, 0.75, -1.5, w, h);
  vertex(-0.25, 0.75, -1.5, 0, h);
  
  //+Y face
  vertex(-0.25, 0.998, -1.0, 0, 0);
  vertex(0.25, 0.998, -1.0, w, 0);
  vertex(0.25, 0.998, -1.5, w, h);
  vertex(-0.25, 0.998, -1.5, 0, h);
  endShape();
 

}


void jump() {
  if (!isJumping) {
    isJumping = true;
    jumpSpeed = -0.6;
  }
}

float rotX = 0, rotY = 0;
float lastX, lastY;
float distX, distY;
void performJump() {
   playerY += jumpSpeed;
  jumpSpeed += 0.02;

  if (playerY >= 0) {
    playerY = 0;
    jumpSpeed = 0;
    isJumping = false;
  }
}
 void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == UP)
    camZ -= 5;
  if (keyCode == DOWN)
    camZ += 5;
  if (key == 'a' || key == 'A')
    playerX -= 0.1;
  if (key == 'd' || key == 'D')
    playerX += 0.1;
  if (key == 'w' || key == 'W')
    playerZ -= 0.1;
  if (key == 's' || key == 'S')
    playerZ += 0.1;
  if (key == ' ')
    jump();
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == UP)
    camZ += 5;
  if (keyCode == DOWN)
    camZ -= 5;
  if (key == 'a' || key == 'A')
    playerX += 0.1;
  if (key == 'd' || key == 'D')
    playerX -= 0.1;
  if (key == 'w' || key == 'W')
    playerZ += 0.1;
  if (key == 's' || key == 'S')
    playerZ -= 0.1;
}

void mouseDragged() {
  float speed = 0.01;
  float distX = (pmouseX - mouseX) * speed;
  float distY = (pmouseY - mouseY) * speed;
  rotX += distY;
  rotY -= distX;
}

void mousePressed() {
  float speed = 0.01;
  distX = 0;
  distY = 0;
  float distX = (pmouseX - mouseX) * speed;
  float distY = (pmouseY - mouseY) * speed;
}

void mouseReleased() {
  distX = 0;
  distY = 0;
}

Hi guys, i have a project in Processing. i am trying to create basic platform game but i could not do it. Can someone help? In this code, I am trying to create a player and this player should go left and right and can jump with space. The blocks I call "stages" should move up and down along the y-axis. The player object I created should also jump on these blocks. If the player touches Lava, the game should stop and "You Failed" should be displayed on the screen. If he successfully passes all 5 blocks and touches the last platform, "Congratulations, You Win!!" should write. Thank you for your help in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have posted the same question across multiple platforms including [Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/plz-want-post-already-ths-question-could-get-wanted-first-don-t-want-code-changed-unless-n-q115775209), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/processing/comments/13yrffs/please_help_it_is_important_3d_platform_game/), and the [Processing Forum](https://discourse.processing.org/t/i-am-trying-to-make-3d-platform-game/42128), asking for a full code solution to your homework assignment. This is generally frowned upon as it undermines the integrity of the academic process and robs you of the opportunity to learn.

A more productive approach is to isolate the parts of the problem that give you trouble, and try to solve them individually. Then you can come to online forums, show your work, and ask for clarifications on those specific issues.